# Calling Close() or Dispose() on MessageQueue does nothing

Tags: c#, msmq, dispose

I am having an issue with calling `Close()` or `Dispose()` on a `MessageQueue`. I got an application that is supposed to be able to manage these message queues. Open and Close them.

But when I call `Close()` or `Dispose()` nothing happens. The queue still exists on the machine. I use the `MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine()` method to get an array of `MessageQueue`'s and it's still in there after calling `Close()` or `Dispose()`. After some reading around it seems that `Dipose()` should be the one I use but still.

This is the code I use to try and close the queue

```
public String CloseQueue(String path)
{
    if (GetQueueArray().Length == 0)
    {
        return "The Queue Array is Empty!";
    }

    foreach (MessageQueue m in GetQueueArray())
    {
        if (m.Path.Equals(path))
        {
            try
            {
                path = m.QueueName;
                m.Close();
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return e.Message;
            }
        }
    }
    return "Successfully Closed Queue at path: " + path;
}
```

The method`GetQueueArray()` is defined as so (in the same class):

```
public MessageQueue[] GetQueueArray()
{
    return MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine(machinename);
}
```

I do this just out of convenience in my GUI Application to call that method when needed.

How do I actually close or dispose of the queues?

Comment: Are you sure it's hitting the line that calls the `Close()` method? Have you tried wrapping your code in a `using()` statement?

Comment: `Vipar` `If MessageQueue class implements IDisposable` also have you tried just setting the `m` Object = null; wrapping in a `using will also be helpful for Auto Disposing` `Stepping through the code` is always best in regards to seeing if expected lines are being hit

Comment: I'm not sure by your post exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You mention that the queue is still there. Close and Dispose will never remove the queue from the machine. They are queues created on that machine and referenced from your application to send/receive messages. If you want to actually REMOVE the queue from the target machine you will need to use Delete. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx as well as nvoigts answer below.

Comment: @gmiley nvoigt already answered with delete. Thank you though :)

Comment: Neither destroy the physical queue, that takes a much bigger weapon.  Do make sure that you *really* want to do this, deleting the queue practically guarantees data loss.  You can never be sure if another machine didn't send a message between the time you retrieved the last message and you disconnected.  Or continues sending messages.  Those messages will be lost, quite the opposite of what a message queue is supposed to do.  If you can afford such loss then a simple TCP connection will be fine.

Comment: @HansPassant I only do this because it's a school project. I would never do that in a real solution for real world use because as you say, that could cause dataloss. Thanks though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Close` or `Dispose` only work for your instance of the message queue C# object. They do not affect the actual message queue. The same way that disposing a database connection will not automatically remove the whole database from the server.

You need to use the static [Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) method of MessageQueue.